# Are there ways to start a Hazelcast Jet instance standalone, and which one is the most performant?

Tags: java, hazelcast-jet

I'm just starting to test Hazelcast Jet on our cluster. Now starting an instance isn't to difficult. BUT: doing so requires a full (albeit small) jar to be executed including a full sized (and probably not optimized) jvm.

Are there alternatives? Like pre-optimized standalone "only start this instance to use a cluster node" packets?

My googling hasn't brought any results, so maybe someone else had more success?

Comment: You mean, like a Docker image of an already running JVM with Jet inside?

Comment: No, more like a minimal java class, which just starts a Jet instance, and has a shutdown hook. I can write this myself, BUT I can't optimize the surrounding jvm to make best use of it. Plus someone knowledgable about Jet might also be able to optimize the java code.

Comment: I'm not aware of anything to optimize about the JVM or the Java code. `Jet.newInstance()` is all it takes.